# MongoDb C# Driver Builders Filter deserialisation exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class with a property

```
  public List<Point> RouteWayPoints { get; set; }
```

Point - is a class of namespace System.Windows

When I Save this object into the Mongo Db - it works. But, when I try to get it from db with builders filter - i have an exception
**An error occurred while deserializing the RouteWayPoints property of class BusLaneRoutes: Value class System.Windows.Point cannot be deserialized.**

```
    private IMongoCollection<BusLaneRoutes> _busLaneRoutesCollection;
    var filter = Builders<BusLaneRoutes>.Filter.Eq("RouteId", routeId);
    var result = _busLaneRoutesCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB C# driver doesn't support deserializing structs. `Point` [is actually a struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx), not a class. Therefore, you see this error.

There's an [open bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-94) requesting a fix for that, which hasn't been updated since 2014. There is a workaround though, as seen in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788855/how-do-you-serialize-value-types-with-mongodb-c-sharp-serializer), involving creating a custom serializer.